# How to implement with Steam Oath 2.0

Tags: javascript

I am making e-commerce site depends on steam auth. I saw this code steam-login package.

```
var express = require('express'),
    steam   = require('steam-login');
 
var app = express();
 
app.use(require('express-session')({ resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, secret: 'a secret' }));
app.use(steam.middleware({
    realm: 'http://localhost:3000/', 
    verify: 'http://localhost:3000/verify',
    apiKey: process.argv[2]}
));
 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user == null ? 'not logged in' : 'hello ' + req.user.username).end();
});
 
app.get('/authenticate', steam.authenticate(), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
 
app.get('/verify', steam.verify(), function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user).end();
});
 
app.get('/logout', steam.enforceLogin('/'), function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
 
app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening');
```

After logged with steam, will it add users to database?

Comment: This is unrelated to [tag:nuxt], hence I'm removing it.

Comment: This is unrelated to strapi, hence I'm removing it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code here to add anything to a database no. It just has a series of calls to the Steam API. Why do you expect this will add anything to a database? If you want to do that, you can write code for whatever you need.